# How to add div content inside a jQuery

Tags: jquery, countdown

I am trying to add content from a div inside to a jQuery function. Please see below:

Content I am trying to add:

```
<div id="year">2020</div>
```

I want to add the year '2020' from '**#year**' div to where it says '**2019**' below in the function:

```
<div id="getting-started"></div>
$('#getting-started').countdown('2019/12/24', function(event) { // <-- here
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D %H %M %S'));
});
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: try:- `$('#getting-started').countdown($('#year').text() +'/12/24', function(event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%D %H %M %S'));
});`

Comment: Fuzion619  did you checked the solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Just extract the contents of the #year div and then create the string using that value

```js
const year = $('#year').text();
$('#getting-started').countdown(`${year}/12/24`, function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%D %H %M %S'));
});
```